# Update people field with a Get-SPOUser on sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I try to update a SharePoint Online people field (in a doc list), from PowerShell.

Here's the code:

```
$properties = $Upload.ListItemAllFields;
$context.Load($properties)
$properties["CLT"] = $File.Name.Substring(0,10)
$spcompte = Get-SPOUser -Site https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/ -LoginName "xxxx@xxxx.onmicrosoft.com" 
$properties["ACCOUNT"] = $spcomte
$properties.Update()
```

No problems with a `$spcompte.displayname`, it shows the correct user,

But `$properties["ACCOUNT"] = $spcomte` just returns the following :

> Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Des données non valides ont été utilisées pour mettre à jour l'élément de liste. Le champ que vous 
>   essayez de mettre à jour est peut-être en lecture seule."
>   At C:\Sharepoint PowerShell.ps1:50 char:1
>   + $Context.ExecuteQuery()
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ServerException

Google translate for the error:

> Invalid data was used to update the list item . The field you are
>   trying to update may be read only.

Any idea? I see a lot of stuff about `Get-SPUser` for SharePoint server, but nothing for Online.

Comment: I would just try setting it with their email address and let it do the validation and everything normally, rather than trying to pass in an object.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I found the solution at last, so I would like to share with you if it helps

```
$SiteUrl = "Your site URL"

$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl) 

$Item["Title of column"] = $Context.Web.EnsureUser("e-mail of user")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the below PowerShell script, we can update the people picker column in SharePoint online:

```
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

#Set parameter values
$SiteURL="https://crescent.sharepoint.com/sites/pmo"
$ListName="Projects"
$FieldName= "ProjectMembers" #Internal Name
$ListItemID="25"
$UserIDs=@("salaudeen.rajack@crescent.com","Charles.jonathan@crescent.com","mark.jones@crescent.com")

#Get Credentials to connect
$Cred= Get-Credential
$Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.Username, $Cred.Password)

#Setup the context
$Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
$Ctx.Credentials = $Credentials

#Get the List & Item to update
$List = $Ctx.Web.lists.GetByTitle($ListName)
$ListItem = $List.GetItemById($ListItemID)
$Ctx.Load($ListItem)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

#Resolve each user ID and get the User Objects
$UserValueColl = @()
ForEach($UserID in $UserIDs)
{
    #Get the User to Update
    $SPOUser = $Ctx.Web.EnsureUser($UserID)
    $Ctx.Load($SPOUser)
    $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

    If($SPOUser -ne $Null)
    {
        $SPOUserValue = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue
        $SPOUserValue.LookupId = $SPOUser.id
        $UserValueColl += $SPOUserValue
    }
}

IF($UserValueColl.length -gt 0)
{
    $UserValueCollCollection = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue[]]$UserValueColl
    #Update the Multi-People picker column
    $ListItem[$FieldName] = $UserValueCollCollection
    $ListItem.Update()
    $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
    Write-Host -f Green "List Item has been updated!"
}
```

Reference URL:

[SharePoint Online: Read / Update Person or Group Field (People Picker) Values using PowerShell](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/10/sharepoint-online-get-set-person-or-group-people-picker-field-using-powershell.html)